# thread notify issue

Tags: java, multithreading

From the main thread, I started a child thread
Inside the child thread `run()` method, call the `wait()` method
In the main method call the `join()` method for the child thread, without notify the child thread.

I noticed, both the main thread as well as the child thread are still running is it a known behaviour? Why?

Comment: Do you mean that the threads are both "Running" in the debugger? If so then that's because the debugger isn't showing you the Thread state but rather whether or not you've paused/suspended the thread in the debugger.

Comment: how are you calling the wait() method when its not in any synchronized context ? (at least you did'nt mention any) It should throw a IllegalMonitorStateException.

Answer (score 4):

By calling `wait` you block the child thread until `notify` and by calling `join` you block the main thread until the child thread ends. Therefore you have a predictable deadlock. I wouldn't call this behavior just "known", but "as specified".